# Work (filter, search etc.) directly on hash from API or store in DB first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am starting to work with big data returned from an API. The API returns thousands of lines in one request like this:

```
"2000-01-06": {
        "1. open": "112.1900",
        "2. high": "113.8700",
        "3. low": "108.3700",
        "4. close": "110.0000",
        "5. volume": "27488300"
    },
    "2000-01-05": {
        "1. open": "111.1200",
        "2. high": "116.3700",
        "3. low": "109.3700",
        "4. close": "113.8100",
        "5. volume": "32029800"
    },
    "2000-01-04": {
        "1. open": "113.5600",
        "2. high": "117.1200",
        "3. low": "112.2500",
        "4. close": "112.6200",
        "5. volume": "27059500"
    },
    "2000-01-03": {
        "1. open": "117.3700",
        "2. high": "118.6200",
        "3. low": "112.0000",
        "4. close": "116.5600",
        "5. volume": "26614200"
    }
```

In the next step I want to work with the data, filter, search, build averages etc. Would it be smart to store the data in my DB first and the work with it or use directly the hash from the api? I am using RoR and Postgres.

My idea is to store the data in a relational DB with columns for date, open, high etc.

Comment: looks a valid json. postgres is very good with json from 9.4 (jsonb) and extremely good from 9.6

Comment: Yes, it's Json, but the question is if I'd better store the data to the DB first.

Comment: In my experience, it's typically better to get the database to do the hard work, especially when the data is static like in your example. It's hard to say for certain in your case, though, as you haven't given many details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you're doing with the data.

1. If the data changes between requests frequently and you only need to run algorithms on it once, just do it in memory:
   It's already in memory in an efficient format (JSON) when you grab it from the API.
   Parsing it into ActiveRecord and storing to disk will be much slower.
2. If you want to run analytics async, or you need to normalize the data for some reason, then you'll need to Objectify the data. It'll be slower, but it's often easier to reason around (and use Ruby or SQL naturally instead of confusing hash management)
3. If you need to access it later, look into skipping ActiveRecord and leaving the database layer just for persistence.